# How to get my animation function in swift to be dependent on the objective c mic blow detection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, viewcontroller, bridging-header

I have a project where my simple png sequence animation code is in a swift file and my microphone detection code is in a .m file. I need to make it so my animation only plays when it detects the blow, but since I have moved my .m and .h files into the project the microphone detection message in the NSLog has stopped appearing. Any ideas on how I do this? which file I need to be working in to link the two etc?

Thanks in advance

Comment: create bridging header you will find many topics about it just use search

Comment: @luzo I have a bridging header

Comment: And yet you do not see the class, do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @luzo  
yes I have a view controller.m and .h and app delegate.m and .h but I am unsure where to write the code that connects this with my .swift code

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to include it in your bridging header, hope this helps. If not you can contact me somehow I will try to help you.

```
#import "TestOBJC.h"

@implementation TestOBJC

- (void)test {
    NSLog(@"test");
}

@end
```

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestOBJC: NSObject

- (void)test;

@end
```

---

Bridging header:

```
#import "TestOBJC.h"
```

---

Swift:

```
let test = TestOBJC()
test.test()
```

Comment: so I have all of those files and have included both view controller.h and app delegate.h in my bridging header. My issues is I don't know how to get the animation code(.swift) to perform the microphone code (.m) is detected. How do I mix the two codes as every time I try to incorporate the two I get an error message saying the code is invalid. Thanks

Comment: Example shows how to expose your objc code to swift, so I do not understand your question right now. You have to show your code, or better share your project on git so I or someone else can help you.